What would happen if the line of effect is blocked after the spell is casted but before taking effect?
So, I would just visualise the case to simplify the question description.

Assuming the Resilient Sphere appears before the spell actually takes place, and it blocks the line of effect.
When something like this happens, would the spell still take effect, would the Caster B simply lose the spell, or can the Caster B pick another spot to make the spell valid again?

By “the line of effect connecting the spellcaster and the original point of origin of the spell,” do you mean the line between the point where contingency was originally cast, however long ago that was, and the point where the caster is when the contingency is triggered? Why would that matter in the slightest?

Also, contingency is a terrible choice of example. It’s an extremely unique spell with notoriously vague rules that aren’t going to be an “example” of how anything else works, because nothing else (clearly) works like contingency does.

@KRyan Probably too many information for the question description. I just simplified it to eliminate those unnecessary conditions.

I have no idea what that table indicates.

A spell's caster picks a legal target when the spell comes into effect
Casting Time, in part, says

You make all pertinent decisions about a spell (range, target, area, effect, version, and so forth) when the spell comes into effect. For example, when casting a summon monster spell, you need not decide where you want the monster to appear (or indeed, what monster you are summoning) until the spell comes into effect in the round after you begin casting. (Player's Handbook 174)

Statements made before a spell comes into effect can be revealed as bald-faced lies once a spell comes into effect. Likewise, a caster who said that he was gonna cast a spell at that guy but when his spell comes into effect finds his line of effect to that guy blocked by a resilient sphere effect can target some other guy with that spell.
